# Close sub-heading in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

Here an org-mode tree

```
* TEST 
 * SUB1
  * SUB11
   * SUB111
   * SUB112
  * SUB12
 * SUB2
```

If the tree is partially fold you can have:

```
* TEST 
 * SUB1
  * SUB11
  * SUB12
 * SUB2
```

Is there a command for (un)folding SUB1 without unfolding SUB11 (like org-cycle) with tab on SUB1 ?
an org-fold-unfold-this-subtree function ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `show-entry` resp. `hide-entry` what you're looking for?

Comment: @mutbuerger. Yes, I am looking for `org-show-entry` and `org-hide-entry` functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found what I was searching for:

```
(define-key org-mode-map (kbd "s-<tab>") 'outline-hide-subtree)
```

do the trick. (shortcut is on Windows_key+TAB)

If you want to overide the backtab (Shift tab) you can do

```
(defalias 'org-shifttab 'outline-hide-subtree)
```